# Loading image in subview without nib

Tags: ios, image

I'm adding a new subview

```
 self.editView = [[EditView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,296) WithImageView:self.mainImageView.image];
            self.mainImageView.hidden=YES;
            [self.view addSubview:self.editView];
```

The New View is:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame WithImageView: (UIImage *) image
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    self.rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotation:)];
    self.pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    self.tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];


    self.panRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.frameView addGestureRecognizer:self.panRecognizer];
    self.rotationRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.rotationRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.frameView addGestureRecognizer:self.rotationRecognizer];
    self.pinchRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.frameView addGestureRecognizer:self.pinchRecognizer];
    self.tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.frameView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];

    [self updateCropRect];

    [self reset:NO];

    self.retainedImage = image;

    self.sourceImage = image;
    self.imageView.image = self.previewImage;

    if(self.previewImage != self.sourceImage) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            CGImageRef hiresCGImage = NULL;
            CGFloat aspect = self.sourceImage.size.height/self.sourceImage.size.width;
            CGSize size;
            if(aspect >= 1.0) { //square or portrait
                size = CGSizeMake(kMaxUIImageSize*aspect,kMaxUIImageSize);
            } else { // landscape
                size = CGSizeMake(kMaxUIImageSize,kMaxUIImageSize*aspect);
            }
            hiresCGImage = [self newScaledImage:self.sourceImage.CGImage withOrientation:self.sourceImage.imageOrientation toSize:size withQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];

          //  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:hiresCGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
                CGImageRelease(hiresCGImage);
          //  });
        });
    }


}
return self;
}
```

Also there are custom setter methods for images.

```
- (UIImage *)previewImage
{
if(_previewImage == nil && _sourceImage != nil) {
    if(self.sourceImage.size.height > kMaxUIImageSize || self.sourceImage.size.width > kMaxUIImageSize) {
        CGFloat aspect = self.sourceImage.size.height/self.sourceImage.size.width;
        CGSize size;
        if(aspect >= 1.0) { //square or portrait
            size = CGSizeMake(kPreviewImageSize,kPreviewImageSize*aspect);
        } else { // landscape
            size = CGSizeMake(kPreviewImageSize,kPreviewImageSize*aspect);
        }
        _previewImage = [self scaledImage:self.sourceImage  toSize:size withQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];
    } else {
        //self.previewImage = [self.sourceImage retain];
        _previewImage = self.retainedImage;
    }
}
return  _previewImage;
```

}

I cannot load the image in the subview. I understand the properties wont be set on init. But how do I set them. I tried using another property retainedImage, and assigning it to preview image in its setter method, but not working.

This is a custom library found [here](https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties for an object will be set to nil when the object is created. If you want to change the properties to other values, you can set them in any methods.

There are many possible reasons why you didn't see the image.

1. self.imageView is nil
2. self.imageView.image is nil
3. the size of self.imageView is 0
4. self.imageView is hidden
5. self.imageView is not attached to any views
6. self.imageView is occluded by other views

From your description, it is hard to tell which one is the reason behind it.